# How to make an Istio EnvoyFfilter apply to two different workloads using workloadSelector

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

I've written an Istio EnvoyFilter. I need to apply this to multiple different workloads in my cluster. It already uses the `workloadSelector` property to choose one of these using the `app` label on the pod, but I can't see how to extend this to select multiple different pods with different `app` labels.

The initial filter looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: set-forwarded-port-header-filter
  namespace: ${NAMESPACE}
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: app1
..etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that by creating a new label (e.g. `filter: my-port-header-filter` or something similar), then apply that label to all workloads you want to apply your filter to.

Then, deploy the EnvoyFilter with a workload selector with the new label to the Istio config root namespace (`istio-system` by default).

With the reason in the root config namespace, the filters will be applied to workloads across the cluster that have that specific label set.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I’ve ended up doing. The workloads that need this fix have the new label set and it’s working. Thanks for answering.